# Create an edges mesh with CGAL

Tags: cgal

I wan't to create a mesh which is composed only of edges and points, but no facets. You can imagine this as several polylines. I have been looking at CGAL halfedge data structures, in particular to the CGAL::Polyhedral_3 class, but apparently it doesn't allow to insert vertices and edges.

Is it possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Using the low level [HDS package](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/HalfedgeDS/index.html) you should be able to remove the support for faces.

However, if you are only looking for a graph, the [Boost Graph Library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html) might be more suitable.